# An array of two objects swapping key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with two objects, I want to be able to swap the key values of the two objects..

```
    "people":[
        {
            "name":"bob",
            "lastname": "johnson",
            "slot_id": 1
        },
        {
            "name":"terry",
            "lastname": "lucas",
            "slot_id": 2
        },
    ]
```

I would like to be able to swap the two slot_id's like so..

```
    "people":[
        {
            "name":"bob",
            "lastname": "johnson",
            **"slot_id": 2**
        },
        {
            "name":"terry",
            "lastname": "lucas",
            **"slot_id": 1**
        },
    ]
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: And what have you tried until now? Can you share with us, then we can help to fix the issue you have on achieving this goal?

Comment: If this was ever to grow, what would it look like - ie if there were three items, how would you swap around?

Comment: So that's the thing im having a hard time wrapping my head around where to start.. I know I have to iterate through, get the slot_id of each then somehow swap them.. It will never grow this is basically being used to update the slot of the people then will go back to being an empty array.. sorry if that's confusing clearly im pretty confused myself lol..

Comment: If you have a hard time where to start on this, you should read another JS tutorial. Preferably one, that isn't aimed at "get started quick", but takes its time to explain properly. The previous one(s) obviously did a bad job.

Comment: thank you for that, now leave some comment room for people that will actually give a answer that isn't rude @ASDFGerte

Comment: @DylanJannetty You have some answers, I've posted one, don't hesitate to ask questions if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: @Mickael B Your ans is correct!  Thanks

Comment: Thanks @MickaelB. looking at it makes a lot of sense, and your answer helped a lot. I'll comment if I have anymore questions.

Comment: @DylanJannetty You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking ✓ on the left. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to swap 2 values, you'll need a temporary variable so you won't lose a value while you assign a new one:

```js
const tmp = people[0].slot_id

people[0].slot_id = people[1].slot_id
people[1].slot_id = tmp
```

---

There is also another possibility if you don't want to use a temporary variable:

```js
people[0].slot_id += people[1].slot_id
people[1].slot_id = people[0].slot_id - people[1].slot_id
people[0].slot_id -= people[1].slot_id
```

You can also use *array destructuring* (proposed by @[ASDFGerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692606/asdfgerte))

```js
[people[0].slot_id, people[1].slot_id] = [people[1].slot_id, people[0].slot_id]
```

Comment: You can do `[people[0].slot_id, people[1].slot_id] = [people[1].slot_id, people[0].slot_id];` if you want to avoid an explicit temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
const person1Id = people[0].slot_id

people[0].slot_id = people[1].slot_id
people[1].slot_id = person1Id
```

Comment: The answer is same as above.  Just you have changed the variable .

Comment: @Forhad did you mean to write this comment on the other post?  If you look at the timestamps I posted this answer before the other answer was submitted...

Comment: I m really sorry. Yeah your answer is correct. Thanks

Comment: @Forhad It was the first answer, I've posted another answer because it was missing explanations and I've added more details and other way to swap variables.